# Relative Layout as Progress Bar [Android]

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

Here is my problem :

I create a list of achievements like this

[image: The goal]

Actually, i have this kind of elements in my list view of achievements

[image: The result I have for the moment]

Here is the xml code of my element in the list :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/relative_layout_rewards">



    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="60dip"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:id="@+id/layout_title_rewards">




        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="5"
            android:text=""
            android:textSize="13sp"
            android:padding="10dip"
            android:id="@+id/title_rewards"
            android:maxLines="2"
            android:textStyle="bold"/>


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/number_rewards"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            android:padding="10dip"
            android:text=""
            android:textStyle="italic"/>



    </LinearLayout>

    <View
        android:id="@+id/rewards_progressbar"
        android:layout_below="@+id/layout_title_rewards"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="3dip"
        android:background="@color/blue"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"/>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/layout_rewards_progress_bar_view"
        android:layout_width="100dip"
        android:layout_height="60dip"
        android:background="@color/blue">


        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/layout_rewards_title_rewards_text"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:textSize="13sp"
            android:padding="10dip"
            android:maxLines="2"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:text="5 points scored in online game"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:ellipsize="end"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/layout_rewards_points_rewards_text"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/layout_rewards_title_rewards_text"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/layout_rewards_title_rewards_text"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            android:padding="10dip"
            android:text="2 / 5"
            android:textStyle="italic"
            android:textColor="@color/white"/>
    </RelativeLayout>


</RelativeLayout>
```

For the second layout that come over the first, I just adjust the width in java according to the percent of the achievement.

I would like the same result as the first picture.

Any ideas ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For that you need to make use of *FrameLayout*

Refer this sample i created. you just replace TextVIew with your content

My activity code

```
public class CustProgress extends Activity {
private FrameLayout mlayFrameLayout;
private RelativeLayout mProgressHolder;
private Handler handler;
private int width = 0, progresswidth = 0;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    mlayFrameLayout = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.progress);
    mProgressHolder = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.progressHolder);
    progresswidth = mProgressHolder.getLayoutParams().width;
    handler = new Handler();
    doProgress();

}

private void doProgress() {
    handler.postDelayed(r, 1000);
}

Runnable r = new Runnable() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
     //if (width <= progresswidth) {
            width=width+10;
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(width,100);
            mlayFrameLayout.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);

            doProgress();
            //          }
    }
};

  }
```

this is my xml code

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/progressHolder"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="100dip" >

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/progress"
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_bright" >
    </FrameLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Loading.." />
    </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Exactly what I need. Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about changing text color and progress view color at the same time.
but i will post the design.

> Use FrameLayout
>
> ```
> <LinearLayout
>     android:id="@+id/layout_title_rewards"
>     android:layout_width="match_parent"
>     android:layout_height="60dip"
>     android:background="#000"
>     android:orientation="horizontal">
>
>
>     <TextView
>         android:id="@+id/title_rewards"
>         android:layout_width="0dip"
>         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>         android:layout_weight="5"
>         android:maxLines="2"
>         android:padding="10dip"
>         android:text=""
>         android:textSize="13sp"
>         android:textStyle="bold" />
>
>
>     <TextView
>         android:id="@+id/number_rewards"
>         android:layout_width="0dip"
>         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>         android:layout_weight="2"
>         android:gravity="center"
>         android:padding="10dip"
>         android:text=""
>         android:textSize="12sp"
>         android:textStyle="italic" />
>
>
> </LinearLayout>
>
>
> <FrameLayout
>     android:id="@+id/layout_rewards_progress_bar_view"
>     android:layout_width="match_parent"
>     android:layout_height="60dip"
>     android:background="@color/colorPrimary">
>
>     <RelativeLayout
>         android:layout_width="match_parent"
>         android:layout_height="match_parent"
>         android:background="@android:color/transparent"
>         android:gravity="center_vertical">
>
>         <TextView
>             android:id="@+id/layout_rewards_title_rewards_text"
>             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>             android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
>             android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
>             android:ellipsize="end"
>             android:maxLines="2"
>             android:padding="10dip"
>             android:text="5 points scored in online game"
>             android:textColor="#fff"
>             android:textSize="13sp"
>             android:textStyle="bold" />
>
>         <TextView
>             android:id="@+id/layout_rewards_points_rewards_text"
>             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>             android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
>             android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
>             android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/layout_rewards_title_rewards_text"
>             android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/layout_rewards_title_rewards_text"
>             android:gravity="end"
>             android:padding="10dip"
>             android:text="2 / 5"
>             android:textColor="#fff"
>             android:textSize="12sp"
>             android:textStyle="italic" />
>     </RelativeLayout>
> </FrameLayout>
>
> <View
>     android:id="@+id/rewards_progressbar"
>     android:layout_width="match_parent"
>     android:layout_height="3dip"
>     android:layout_marginTop="60dip"
>     android:background="@color/com_facebook_blue" /> </FrameLayout>
> ```

now set progress for FarmeLayout (i.e id `layout_rewards_progress_bar_view` )